# Generate a three dimensional array in python by iterating through a list

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, numpy

I appreciate that this task is probably a bit ambitious given my level (or lack) of knowledge, but still.

I have a list of 16 character strings, about 3000 items long, where each character denotes another list of numbers. Not sure if I'm making that clear; what it actually is a list of 16-amino acid long peptides, where each of the amino acids (1 of 20) is representable by 5 numbers.

I want to iterate through that list (of peptides), and then for each character (amino acid) add the relevant 5 numbers (Atchley factors, if you're interested) to an array, making a 3 dimensional array, where my axes are: instance of peptide (3000) x amino acid within that peptide (16) x factors (5).

I'm incredibly out of my depth, so I'm not sure if what I've got is useful is helpful, but here it is (using numpy):

```
array = np.empty(shape=(len(peptides),16,5)

for i in peptides:

    for j in str(i):
```

(and at this point I tried a bunch of different things as I trawled the forums, ending with something a little like this, but I'm sure I've missed even what I was aiming for here)

```
    if j == 'A':    
            L16Afctrs = np.append([-0.59145974, -1.30209266, -0.7330651, 1.5703918, -0.14550842], axis=1)
    elif j == 'C':
            L16Afctrs = np.append([-1.34267179, 0.46542300, -0.8620345, -1.0200786, -0.25516894], axis=1)
    ...
    elif j == 'Y':
            L16Afctrs = np.append([0.25999617, 0.82992312, 3.0973596, -0.8380164, 1.51150958], axis=1)
```

Like I say, I'm honestly struggling, any help would be much appreciated.

**Edit: clarification (hopefully)**

I have a list of around 3000 different 16 character strings, where each character in those strings denotes a further 5 numbers.

I want to generate a 3 dimensional array or structure, whereby I can (eventually) plot those 5 numbers for a given position across all 3000 strings, by looking across a given plane in the 3 dimensional array (where the dimensions I envisage are; original string x 16 characters x 5 factors).

I'm currently in the process of making a dictionary of the different characters, relating to the post from @Winston, then trying to fold that into a 3d array.

**Edit 2: Success!**

Winston's fix works beautifully!

Comment: There's an *awful* lot of repeated data in that array.  Are you sure you're not better off using a lookup dictionary with your amino acid as a key, and the factors as a value in the next step?

Comment: try to rephrase your explanation and make your data structure VERY clear! like: sample=[peptide_0, .. peptide_n], peptide = 16 char string; each peptide-string maps to a 5 item long list of numbers: peptide_to_whatever_map = { peptide_0 : [1,2,3,4,5], ..., peptide_n:[0,1,2,3,4] } - restrain to explain what the data-strucutre represent but abstract it as far as possible. welocme to SO btw ;-) Fell free to completly overhaul your question and reduce the ammount  of redundant information. If you want help consider we have to read it and don't want to sort relevant from the irrelevant parts out

Comment: I see your points, that makes a lot of sense! I knew I was going about this the wrong way, just didn't know where to look - thanks!

Comment: And thanks @Don, will think about how to rephrase it - wasn't sure if I had to be careful about not editing original questions..?

Comment: feel free to edit away, as long as you improve your original question without starting to change the core of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store your data in a dictionary:

```
DATA = {
    'A' : numpy.array([-0.59145974, -1.30209266, -0.7330651, 1.5703918, -0.14550842]),
    'B' : numpy.array([-1.34267179, 0.46542300, -0.8620345, -1.0200786, -0.25516894]),
    'D' : numpy.array([1.05015062, 0.30242411, -3.6559147, -0.2590236, -3.24176791])
    ...
}
```

Use a python list comprehension to build a list of all those, and then have numpy convert that list into a numpy array

```
counters = numpy.array([DATA[letter] for peptide in peptides for letter in peptide])
```

Reshape the array into your 3D dimensions, since the last step will have 2D arrays

```
counters = counters.reshape( len(peptides), 16, 5 )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Winston, I'm going to give this a go!

Comment: OK, I've been trying to implement this for a little while, but I appear to be running up against a problem I can't solve. I keep getting the following errors:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Factors.py", line 72, in <module>
    counters = counters.reshape( len(peptides), 16, 5 )
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged`

Chasing this up, it seems that the `counters = numpy.array([DATA` line is converting peptides from a list ~3k long, to a 16 long string, so the resize obviously fails...

Comment: OK, so in looking a bit closer, I realise that the `counters = numpy.array([DATA[letter] for...` line is actually removing all the data in the peptides, so I assume I've implemented this line wrong. I have `counters = np.array([DATA[letter] for peptide in peptide for letter in peptide])`.

Comment: @jayemee, show me the values of `len(peptides)` and `counters.shape`

Comment: Before the `counters = np.array...` line, len(peptides) = 2947 (and it's a list). After that line, len(peptides) = 16, and it's a string (because there's only one instance of a 16 character string in the array). `counters.shape` gives (47152, 5). The 47k number looks like it's 16 times the number of entries there should be, so it's multiplied those axes together.

Comment: @jayemee, check for the `for peptide in peptides` in the list comprehension. It sounds like you have done `for peptides in peptides`?

Comment: You're right, sorry I had, must have confused myself in the edit! This looks like it's working, will just try and check the right values are being assigned to the right peptides! 
**edit** Just checked, it looks like it's working a treat! Thanks so much @Winston, now I just need to figure out how to pull information out of this!